# How to connect extern files in TASM x64

Tags: assembly, tasm, x86-16

I cannot connect external files to my program. I am trying to connect a file filled with macros. I have all the files in the same folder. So, HOW DO I PROPERLY EXTERN THESE FILES SO THAT I CAN CALL THE MACROS THAT ARE IN THEM ?

CODE:

```
include PCMAC.INC
    .model small
    .stack 100h

    .data
Prompt_a DB 'Enter A:$'
Prompt_b DB 'Enter B:$'
Output  db  'The sum is $'
CR  EQU 0dh ;13 \r moves the cursor to begginig of current row
LF  EQU 0ah ;10 new line  

    .code
   EXTERN GETDEC:NEAR, PUTDEC:NEAR 
   main proc 
        mov ax, @data
        mov ds, ax

        _PutStr Prompt_a
        call    GETDEC  ;number in AX after
        mov bx, ax
        _PutStr Prompt_b
        call GETDEC ; still in AX
        add bx, ax
        _PutStr Output
        mov ax, bx
        call   PUTDEC   ;Print num in AX
        _PUTCH 13, 10

        _exit 0 ; Finished/return to dos 
        main endp
        end main
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
  Assembling file:   test.asm
**Error** test.asm(13) Illegal instruction
**Error** test.asm(19) Undefined symbol: GETDEC
**Error** test.asm(22) Undefined symbol: GETDEC
**Error** test.asm(26) Undefined symbol: PUTDEC
  Error messages:    4
  Warning messages:  None
  Passes:            1
  Remaining memory:  455k
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply `INCLUDE` the file and use the macros.

The `EXTRN` directive, note the **missing** `E`<sup>†</sup>, is used to declare a symbol, like a function, defined in another object file<sup>1</sup> that is usually the result of a separate source file (this is typical when mixing C and assembly).

**Note**
The `INCLUDE` directive is like a copy-paste of the content of the included file in place of the directive.
Make sure that the included content is compatible with the "surrounding" - i.e. make sure that copy-pasting the content of the file will generate a correct source.

To use a macro, by its nature of meta-code<sup>2</sup>, the assembler needs to have access to its code, so `INCLUDE` is the right directive<sup>3</sup> since it copies the source code of the macro in the current file.

**Example**

*macros.asm*

```
exit MACRO

  mov ax, 4c00h
  int 21h

ENDM
```

*program.asm*

```
.8086
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100h

;Macros are fine here
INCLUDE mc2.asm

_CODE SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'CODE' USE16
 ASSUME CS:_CODE, DS:_CODE

 ORG 100h

__START__:

 ;This is the macro in the macros.asm file
 exit


_CODE ENDS

END __START__
```

Note that you have to assemble and link *program.asm*, the other file, *macros.asm* is a satellite file (like the headers in C).

---

<sup>†</sup> `EXTERN` is not a valid directive and generates the error reported

<sup>1</sup> For the tech-savvy, it will create an entry `8Ch` in the [OMF](http://pierrelib.pagesperso-orange.fr/exec_formats/OMF_v1.1.pdf) object file *.OBJ* generated by TASM.

<sup>2</sup> It's code that reason about, and generate, code.

<sup>3</sup> For the tech-savvy, `EXTRN` makes no sense here since external symbols reduce to a 2/4 bytes offset and a (type) index that contains debug information in the [Object Module Format (OMF)](http://pierrelib.pagesperso-orange.fr/exec_formats/OMF_v1.1.pdf) used by DOS Object files.

---

**Appendix**

This is a bit off-topic and not necessary to answer the question, the reader can stop reading, if it feels overwhelmed, without any loss.

To better grasp the difference between the `INCLUDE`ing a symbol and `EXTRN`ing it, here is presented the same program that uses an externally defined `exit` function instead of a macro.

*Library.asm*

```
.8086
.MODEL SMALL  

PUBLIC exit

_CODE SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'CODE' USE16
 ASSUME CS:_CODE, DS:_CODE

 exit:
   mov ax, 4c00h
   int 21h

   ;No need to ret

_CODE ENDS

;No need for an entry-point
END
```

*Program.asm*

```
.8086
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100h

;The type PROC is necessary or TASM will interpret the symbol
;as a variable generating an indirect call! e.g. call [exit]
EXTRN exit:PROC


_CODE SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'CODE' USE16
 ASSUME CS:_CODE, DS:_CODE

 ORG 100h

__START__:

 call exit


_CODE ENDS

END __START__
```

This time **both** *Library.asm* and *Program.asm* must be assembled and the resulting object files must be linked together with *TLINK*.

Comment: You have provided the correct answer, but I suspect you may have additionally answered several levels too deeply (w/ OMF records) which may lead to confusion for the OP.

Comment: mmm, maybe you are right @wallyk. Let's see if I can rearrange the answer in a better way